# Send data from an iOS app when connection is restored

Tags: ios

I'm creating an app that allows the user to work without internet connection. When he wants to publish his progress to the web server it gets stored in the device's database. If he isn't connected to the internet I have to send it when he gets internet connection back.

How can I run the code to send the data to the database when internet connection is available again?

In Android I used a broadcast receiver to listen for a "connection changed" event to accomplish this but I don't seem to find a way in iOS to do the same.

Comment: google: ios reachability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to check if the device has an active internet connection (3G and/or Wi-Fi for iPhone, Wi-Fi for iPad/iPod Touch), there are many ways to do that but the simplest in my opinion is to use **Reachability**.

Check this [**similar question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk) for more informations about Reachability and how to implement it in your project. It can even be used in a `if statement` so you can make the user able to publish or not depending on his internet connection.